# How do I take data from a CSV file, and parse the data into an INT between two commas?

Tags: c++, string, parsing

First off, apologies for how unspecific this question may be, for it is my first time asking a question of StackOverflow.

I will get down to business, I am working on a project which reads a file (CSV specifically) and will then save certain data from there into an Int i will later mess with.

Essentially, my code is currently as followed:

```
            if (!infile) {
            cout << "You entered something that cannot be opened, please try again." << endl;
            Continue = true;
        }
        else {
            while (infile.good()) {
                getline(infile, value, ','); // read a string until next comma
                cout << string(value, 1, value.length() - 2); // display value removing the first and the last character from it
            }
            Continue = false;
        }
    }
```

So far, this reads the data and outputs lines that look like this:

```
    2014-01-03,"2014","01","03","†","-12.8","","-31.0","","-21.9","","39.9","","0.0","","","M","","M","0.0","","","","","","<31",""
2014-01-04,"2014","01","04","†","-2.3","","-12.8","","-7.6","","25.6","","0.0","","","M","","M","2.9","","40","","18","","39",""
2014-01-05,"2014","01","05","†","-2.1","","-4.1","","-3.1","","21.1","","0.0","","","M","","M","16.2","","52","","8","","32",""
```

My information needed is between the 5th and 6th comma (it represents the average temperature for the day) and I somehow need to put the information between those two commas into some kind of int.

As well, between the 3rd and 4th comma is the day, which I will need later to calculate the average temperature for each month, so I need to figure that out as well.

Does anyone know the correct way to go about doing this? Unfortunately my knowledge of string parsing is to be desired.

Comment: Please search before progressing.  There are already a plethora of similar questions that can be found by searching the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file comma separated"

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the values between the 5th and 6th commas are floating-point numbers - you should to convert it into either **float** or **double**.

Then,

If both

- you always have a “.” as a separator in the floating-point numbers
- C++17 or higher versions of the language is acceptable for you
  use **std::from_chars** (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars)

If not, consider the following:

- for signed integers - **std::stoi**/**std::stol**/**std::stoll** (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)
  and **std::strtol**/**std::strtoll** (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)
- for unsigned integers - **std::stoul**/**std::stoull** (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) and **std::strtoul**/**std::strtoull** (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul)
- for floating-point numbers - **std::stof**/**std::stod**/**std::stold** (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), **std::strtof**/**std::strtod**/**std::strtold** (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) and for wide-character strings **std::wcstof**/**std::wcstod**/**std::wcstold** (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcstof)

If your compiler does not support the functions above, your only options are
**atoi**/**atol** (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi)
and **atof** (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof), and **sscanf** (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).